# Arch Linux remapping keys

Tags: arch-linux, button-remapping

I was interested in installing Arch (or more specifically archbang) but could not figure out how to remap CAPSLOCK to ESC.

I tried loadkeys, but it had an `error: could not get a file descriptor referring to the console`

I'm used to using GNOME, where it is as easy as going into a menu and switching them. How do I do this on Arch?

Comment: Yeah I think using the xmodmap utility approach is what you're looking for, though there are plenty of search results that crop with with `loadkeys`. I think `xmodmap` is more appropriate for your use-case -- as it's a utility for modifying keymaps vs. customizing keyboard for locale.

Answer (score 7):

I am using this in my ~/.Xmodmap:

```
! who needs CapsLock anyway
clear Lock
keycode 66 = Escape
```

It only disables CapsLock so basically [CapsLock] and [Esc] act the same way on my system.

I also have following line in ~/.xinitrc to load my customized keyboard map whenever X starts.

```
if [ -s ~/.Xmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
fi
```

You will find more solutions on the [arch-forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=141933).

The following solutions are just copied from the above link for reference.

This should be put in ~/.Xmodmap to switch both Keys. You also have to load your modified .Xmodmap file from .xinitrc.

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
add Lock = Escape
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
keysym Escape = Caps_Lock
```

Or if you prefer another program instead of xmodmap, add following line to ~/.xinitrc:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:escape
```

Answer (score 0):

Also documented in the official docs: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap#Turn_CapsLock_into_Control

Basically three steps:

1. Dump the current key map using `xmodmap`
2. Modify the keymap & apply
3. Configure system to load custom setup on startup

Gotcha: Need to clear previous maps before apply new maps (documented).